# Python find duplicates and merge data based on time

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, arcpy

I have a table with around 3500 records.

I am trying to loop through and find duplicates based on a field i created called UNIQUEID, which could be 2, 3, 4 of each record. My end goal is to merge records that have identical UNIQUEID values, but different RTYPE values

```
OID    UNIQUEID       RTYPE     TIME      OTHER
 1   ABC_20170215     SENT      12:30     item1
 2   ABC_20170215   RECEIVED    12:29     
 3   ABC_20170215     SENT      12:35     item4
```

Now when i find my duplicates, i want to check RTYPE and if RTYPE is different, then do the math to figure out which one is closest in time and merge those two.

So my end goal, in the table above, records 1 and 2 would be merged, and I don't care about columns like RTYPE or TIME but if there is data, I want to keep it for columns like OTHER.

So here is the code that I have so far that looks for duplicates, which I think is giving me some problems with multiples.

```
 ###set up cursors
cursor1 = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, ["UNIQUEID", "RTYPE"])
cursor2 = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, ["UNIQUEID", "RTYPE"])
count = 0
#make a dictionary and store values from my table
idUnique = {}
for row in cursor1:
  idUnique[row[0]] = row[0]
  idUnique[row[1]] = row[1]

#loop through other table
for row in cursor2:
    if row[0] == idUnique[row[0]]:
        print "Row 1 {}".format(row[0]) + " --{}".format(row[1])
        print "ID Row 1 {}".format(idUnique[row[0]]) + " --{}".format(idUnique[row[1]])
```

Any help would be amazing!

My expected output would be

```
OID    UNIQUEID       RTYPE         TIME            OTHER
 1   ABC_20170215   <whatever>   <whatever>         item1
 3   ABC_20170215   <whatever>   <whatever>         item4
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: may be `df.groupby()`will help!

Comment: What error or incorrect output are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating only a single cursor, in order to get your data into a dictionary, and then work on manipulating the data from there. Since you have to make a dictionary *anyway* to store information for the next loop through, might as well just use the dictionary. (I *would* recommend a second cursor only if you're going to loop through a different feature class.)

```
unique_ids = []
all_data = {}
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, ["FID", "UNIQUEID", "RTYPE", "TIME", "OTHER"])
for row in cursor:
    if row[1] not in unique_ids:
        unique_ids.append(row[1])
    all_data[row[0]] = {
        "uniqueid": row[1],
        "rtype": row[2],
        "time": row[3],
        "other": row[4]
    }
```

At this point, you can start going through the dictionary to find duplicates, compare attributes, and determine what to keep and what to discard.

Comment: i think my main problem is there may be more than 2 duplicates. there could be 4 of the same record with differences in time -> minutes that i need to query and merge based on the smallest difference in time    I honestly think pandas would work best, i've never used it in for something in any way complicated

Comment: Once you've got the dictionary out using the SearchCursor, that should be able to go into pandas. That's further outside my area of expertise, though :)